# How to disable PotPlayer checking for updates at Start up

Tags: daum-pot-player

It would be helpful to block the PotPlayer checking for update window pop-up during PotPlayer startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I disable PotPlayer update checks?

- Open the Preferences window, either click on the PotPlayer icon on the upper bar and click on Preferences, or press <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Go to the General tab
- Look for the fields related to updates like "Automatic Updates", or "Auto check for update", and disable it
- Disable any other fields related to update and update download processes
- Click on Ok to save your modifications

Source: [How to stop PotPlayer update](https://ccm.net/sound-image/tv-video/3387-disable-automatic-updates-on-daum-potplayer/)

> [image]

Source: [How to Disable Potplayer Update Permanently](https://quickfever.com/disable-potplayer-update/)